# Laravel Error: Unable to prepare route [login] for serialization

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-sanctum

I'm getting a Laravel error when trying to clear the routes cache:
Unable to prepare route `login` for serialization. Another route has already been assigned the name `auth.login`.
I have two auth routes:

```
Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('auth.login')->middleware('web');
Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'authenticate'])->name('auth.login');
```

I know the error is there because there are two routes with the same name. But if I remove the name from the POST route, when I go to the login screen URL, I get a 405 Method not allowed error. This is very strange because the POST route is only used when I type the credentials and click the Login button, not when I go to the login screen URL. Everything works fine with the same names in both routes, but that doesn't make sense.

`showLoginForm` method is a default method.
authenticate method is a custom method:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->firstOrFail();
        session()->regenerate();
        $user = Auth::user();
        if (session('saved') == null) {
            Session::put('email', $request->email);
            Session::put('password', $request->password);
        }

        return redirect()->intended(route('home'));
    }

    return back()->withErrors([
        'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: are you using default authentication or writting your own authentication methods.if so show us controller code as well

Comment: using "Auth::routes();" I get the 405 Method Not Allowed error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a Laravel bug.

If I run:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

I get the 405 Method Not Allowed error.

But then if I run:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure the reason you're getting this issue is because you have two routes with the same name. Remove the `->name('login')` from the `post` route and it should solve the issue:

```
Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])
    ->name('auth.login')
    ->middleware('web');
Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'authenticate']);
```

Comment: Sure, but as I've written in the question, if I remove the name from the POST route, I get the 405 Method Not Allowed error.

Comment: This is the real problem, why am I getting this method not allowed error?

Comment: It seems like there must have a POST login route even if it's not being used on the login screen. That's very strange.

Comment: The route should still exist, it's just the name is only used for the GET route. This shouldn't be an issue though as the URI for both routes is the same. Please can you exist your question and show where you're using the route name that causes the issue.